# A problem on Riemann Stieltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$ \int_{0}^2  x\,d \alpha $  where $ \alpha (x) = x $ if $ 0\le x\le 1 $ and $ \alpha(x)=2+x  $  when $ 1<x\le 2 $  I did this by taking a partition which divided the interval $[0,2]$ to $2n$ equal parts

$P=\left\{{0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\dots,\frac{n}{n}=1,1+\frac{1}{n},\dots,2\cdot\frac{n}{n}=2}\right\}$

and considered a Riemann sum using $t_ i=x_i$ where $t_i \in $[$x_{k-1},x_k$] and by taking the limit when $n$ goes to infinity got $3$ as the answer. I wanted to check if its correct and if so why is it wrong to do it as below

$ \int_{0}^2  x d \alpha  =  \int_{0}^1  x d x  + \int_{1}^2  x d (x+2) $  would get $2$ as the answer?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The question is what happens at the "jump".  In your case, the jump is at the point $1$, so
$$
\int_{1}^2  x\; d (x+2) \ne \int_1^2 x\, d\alpha(x)
$$

Comment: It must change to equality by the theorem  $$\int_a^bfdG=\int_a^bfG'dx$$ when $G$ is differentiable.

Comment: A function like $\alpha$, which is not continuous, is of course not differentiable at the point $1$.

Comment: What about $\alpha=I-x?$